# Does GC_MALLOC actually correspond to calloc()?

Tags: c, garbage-collection, boehm-gc

According to the manual, `GC_MALLOC` clears the memory but `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC` does not clear the memory.

```
void * GC_MALLOC(size_t nbytes)
Allocates and *clears* nbytes of storage.

void * GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC(size_t nbytes)
Allocates nbytes of storage.
```

https://www.hboehm.info/gc/gcinterface.html

So `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC` should be used to replace `malloc` and  `GC_MALLOC` should be used to replace `calloc`? Is it so?

Answer (score 1):

> So `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC` should be used to replace `malloc` and `GC_MALLOC` should be used to replace `calloc`? Is it so?

No.

You are correct that `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC()` is like `malloc()` in that `malloc()` makes no guarantee to clear the allocated space, whereas `GC_MALLOC()` is like `calloc()` in that it does clear the allocated space, but in the most general sense, you should replace *both* `malloc()` and `calloc()` with `GC_MALLOC()`.  This is because,

1. `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC()` documents this constraint:

   > The client promises that the resulting object will never contain any pointers.
2. Objects that do contain pointers must be cleared when allocated so that GC can be confident about its interpretation of those objects when it scans them for pointers.

On the other hand, one usually has some knowledge about the usage of the space one is allocating, and when one does, `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC()` is to be preferred for objects that do not contain pointers.  This is because GC will not (ever) spend time scanning the resulting objects for pointers.  If you want the results zero-filled, then do that manually, afterward. `memset()` is a common means to do this.